# what is @ sign as a css selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw this in a css file:

```
@-webkit-keyframes loading-spinner-anim {
  0% { opacity: 1}
  100% {opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes loading-spinner-anim {
  0% { opacity: 1}
  100% {opacity: 0}
}
```

what do these selectors mean?

`@keyframes` it's not a class or id selector.

`loading-spinner-anim` - the space means it's a child element of the first selector. But it's not a class or id selector.

Comment: Keyframes are css 'functions', like media query's

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule) is always useful.

Comment: what about the old & good google search?? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not selectors at all. They are [at-rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#at-rules) and have many different purposes.

The particular example you have there is the [keyframes at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) which:

> lets authors control the intermediate steps in a CSS animation sequence by establishing keyframes (or waypoints) along the animation sequence that must be reached by certain points during the animation.

Other at-rules include [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) for loading external stylesheets, [@charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset) for specifying the character encoding used by the stylesheet and [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) for limiting when a collection of rulesets will be applied.